# the size of a down-set?

Tags: co.combinatorics, computational-number-theory, extremal-set-theory

I'm reading a research article lately, and got confused about a question. 
So, the fundamental theorem of Kruskal and Katona states that if each set in a given set system $\mathcal{A}$ has $k$ elements and $|\mathcal{A}|=m$, then the lower shadow of $\mathcal{A}$ is at least as large as the lower shadow of the initial segment of length $m$ of $N^{(k)}$ in the colex order. Here, $N^{(k)}$ is the family of all $k$-element sets of all the natural numbers. Then, the article mentioned that, as an easy consequence of this Kruskal-Katona theorem, we have the following lemma:

If $\mathcal{F}$ is a down-set, $||\mathcal{F}|| \leq || \mathcal{I}(|\mathcal{F}|) ||$. Here, $\mathcal{I}(m)$ is the initial segment of length $m$ of $N^{(<\inf)}$ in the colex order. Here, $N^{(<\inf)}$ is the family of all the finite subsets of all natural numbers. I did not see the reasoning behind this. Could anyone give me a hint of this? Many thanks for your time and attention.

Comment: Not every question involving sets is a set theory question. You didn't tag this as number theory, despite the fact that were numbers involved (k, m, etc.)...

Comment: I'd say it should be tagged number theory and combinatorics

Comment: based on the article, it is simply an easy consequence of Kruskal and Katona's result.

Comment: why not give a precise reference to the article?

Comment: what is a down-set and what is denoted by $||\mathcal{F}||$?

Comment: @j.c.: This is Tom Eccles's "A stability result for the union-closed size problem", Lemma 2.2. (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1311.2298.pdf)

Comment: @FedorPetrov: $\|\mathcal F\|$ is the sum of the sizes of all sets from $\mathcal F$, and $\mathcal F$ is a downset if, along with every set, it contains all its subsets.

Comment: and what is a colex order on finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: @FedorPetrov: $A<B$ if $\max(A\Delta B)\in B$.

Answer (score 1):

The inequality the OP is asking for seems to be

- little else than the inequality one gets by *summing all the finitely-many inequalities in the relevant instance of the usual Kruskal-Katona theoreom*.

Just take any usual statement of the Kruskal-Katona theorem, adapt the statement you took to your context, and then *sum* all the inequalities between f-vector-components.

I did not quite work out the details, yet it seems that there is essentially nothing more in the "Lemma 2.2" you cite. The difficulty of *deriving* the inequality asked for by the OP *seems* comparable to the difficulty of deriving $a+c\leq b+d$ from ($a\leq b$ $\wedge$ $c\leq d$)  .

Is that enough to help you get on with it?

**Remarks.**

- A reference you could use is [Samuel Kolins: *Notes For Algebraic Methods in Combinatorics 2008*. Theorem 1.45](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~eranevo/homepage/FaceRingNotes.pdf). Sum the inequalities therein and see whether this answers your question for you.
- The Kruskal-Katona theorem is a *characterization* of the second-order  predicate '$\exists$ at least one abstract simplicial complex whose f-vector is the given vector'$\colon$ $\omega^{d+1}\to\{$true,false$\}$ by a, in a sense, first-order predicate, using another signature though, which says 'for each index the relevant inequality between the components holds'. I would bet that the inequality you are asking about is *only* necessary, i.e., $\mathcal{F}$ need not be a 'down-set' if it happens to hold. (I haven't stopped to think about this, however. Yet it seems trivial to find examples that this inequality from Lemma 2.2 is not equivalent to the Kruskal-Katona theorem; basically, any random example should work as a counterexample; I know you didn't claim it to be equivalent anywhere, it just seems good to mention this.
- Worth pointing out: a usual synonym for 'down-set' is '*abstract simplicial complex*'.

Comment: Could you explain more clearly from a combinatorial sense? @Peter Heinig

Comment: @JosephStone: re "could you explain": probably yes, unfortunately, no time today. Hope to get round to in the next few days. Again: from what I saw, there does not seem to be much of a problem here. Just sum the inequalities. The inequality you stated seems to be the sum of the component-wise inequalities.